# Query with Join and calculation

Tags: database, oracle

I need to create a query based on the following question:

I need to add the number of instructors and students that have the same zip and if it is more than 10 then list the city, state, total number of instructors, total number of students, and the total from adding the instructors and students together.
All three tables have the zip field that they share. It is the primary key in the zipcode table and a foreign key in the instructor and student table. The city and state fields are in the zipcode table. I initially had this query but no rows are returned. I can't get the total. Every time I incorporate either SUM or addition I get a ORA 00923 From keyword not found where expected error.

```
select city, state, 'TOTAL'
from zipcode
left join
(select student.zip, count(*) 'Total_Stud'
from student
group by zip)
s on zipcode.zip=student.zip
left join
(select instructor.zip, count(*) 'Total_Inst'
from instructor
group by zip)
i on zipcode.zip=instructor.zip
where count(student.student_id) + count(instructor.instructor_id)>=10 as total
order by total desc;
```

There are 3 tables involved
Student Table, instructor and zipcode

Comment: Before your next question, I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I  think you were quite close, but when you use subqueries, use the aliases of the subquery and the column names/aliases provided by the subquery. E.g. you may use the alias `s.Total_Stud` in the final where clause. You cannot directly refer to the student table in that where clause because that is only available inside the subquery known as s. This can be referred to as "scope" of the subquery which I have tried to identify below.

```
select zipcode.city, zipcode.state, (NVL(s.Total_Stud,0) + NVL(i.Total_Inst,0)) TOTAL
from zipcode 
left join (
    -- -------------- scope ------------------- -- student 
    select student.zip, count(*) Total_Stud     -- student 
    from student                                -- student 
    group by zip                                -- student 
    -- -------------- scope ------------------- -- student 
    ) s on zipcode.zip=s.zip
left join (
    -- ------------- scope -------------------- -- instructor 
    select instructor.zip, count(*) Total_Inst  -- instructor 
    from instructor                             -- instructor 
    group by zip                                -- instructor 
    -- ------------ scope --------------------- -- instructor 
    ) 
    i on zipcode.zip=i.zip
where (NVL(s.Total_Stud,0) + NVL(i.Total_Inst,0)) >=10
order by (NVL(s.Total_Stud,0) + NVL(i.Total_Inst,0)) desc, zipcode.city;
```

Note that as each `left join` can lead to unmatched rows (e.g. a city with no students) then the counts of students or instructors may be absent, so when adding these together we must avoid NULL, hence I have used the `NVL()` function to replace NULL with zero. `COALESCE()` could be used instead of `NVL()`

Finally also note that in Oracle you want to avoid using quoted column names/aliases, if you do this they become "case sensitive" and that gets very painful to use. (So, this also means to avoid spaces in column names/aliases.)

For a demonstration see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d1245dbf39ebb0d6193ee4ba717d962)*

Comment: I ran your query and no errors. Only no rows returned

Comment: Sorry, please refresh and try the latest query. I have been attempting to answer without a keyboard and now I have one in front of me I have been able to do more. Also try removing the where clause, I cannot see you data so no clue what the results you see are.

Comment: still no rows returned

Comment: the output should be 5 columns

Comment: city, state, total students, total instructors, and addition of student and instructor. There are 10 records in the instruction table and 268 records in the student table. So I think there should only be one instance where adding student and instructors with the same zip would be more than 10. Like I think there is one instructor that shares the same zip with 9 students.

Comment: I meant instructor not instruction

Comment: so make it 5 columns.... you choose which columns, entirely up to you. Have yo solved the rows yet? remember I CANNOT see any data - TRY REMOVING the where clause completely

Comment: all the rows total is null except 1.

Comment: when I run this query

Comment: select instructor.zip, count(*) Total_Inst  
    from instructor                             
    group by zip

Comment: the result is    zip            TOTAL_INST

Comment: I have answered the question. You are now grappling with issues related to DATA and I have no control over that... I repeat I CANNOT see any data.  **UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCES** try to put data into one of these comments. If you are going to add data, EDIT the question (there is a link provided to do that)

Comment: there are 5 records  zip 10025 has 4 instructors

Comment: Go [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d1245dbf39ebb0d6193ee4ba717d962) **please** . I have provided **sample** data. If you cannot make this work for you now I really don't know what more I can offer. Over to you.

Comment: is there a place where I can add a file? I created a screenshot but I don't see where I can add a file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53422270/edit ... look for the word Edit underneath your question. But, honestly, I have done enough. **The query works**, all you need to do is figure out how it works with your data.

Comment: have you looked at my db-fiddle demonstration at all?

Comment: yes I have it looks like what I need. I will keep playing around with it

Comment: here are 2 other "fiddles": http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1c97/3 and  https://rextester.com/VBLC89594 all with the same sample data but  each of these sites have different strengths/weaknesses. Good Luck.

Comment: did you get what you needed?

Comment: Run it without the WHERE clause and start debugging your data from there.